# Lucene Query on a DateField indexed by Solr

Tags: solr, lucene

We are using a solr index for various search applications. In most cases we use it just as you would with the admin interface. 
for example:

```
+text:Mr +text:burns +publish_date[2012-09-10T00:00:00Z TO 2012-10-10T00:00:00Z]
```

This works fine.
My problem is that in one app we use complex lucene Queries directly against the index (without using solr) and in these queries i cant find how to search on a date field.
In schema.xml:

```
<field name="publish_date" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

It seems that solr stores the date as unix time in milliseconds, when pulling the field from the index it looks like that **1336867200000**

In lucene I've tried every query I can think of:

```
TermRangeQuery nq1 = new TermRangeQuery("publish_date",  "1299628800000", "1336867200000", true, true);
TermRangeQuery nq1 = new TermRangeQuery("publish_date",  "1299628800", "1336867200", true, true);
TermRangeQuery nq1 = new TermRangeQuery("publish_date",  "2012-09-10T00:00:00Z", "2012-10-10T00:00:00Z", true, true);
TermRangeQuery nq1 = new TermRangeQuery("publish_date",  "20120910", "20121010", true, true);
NumericRangeQuery nq1 = NumericRangeQuery.newLongRange("publish_date", 1299628800, 1336867200, true, true);
```

and a few other tries...
The only query that did return results was

```
TermRangeQuery nq1 = new TermRangeQuery("publish_date",  null, null, true, true);
```

Of course this is a query with "Open endpoints" but it does seem to apply that the field is indexed as string (the same didn't work with int-range or long-range).
The frustrating thing is that it is obviously possible, I just have to figure out how dose solr preforms it's date range.
Anyone knows how to perform this search?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "1336867200000" is a timestamp, yes.

```
TermRangeQuery nq1 = new TermRangeQuery("publish_date",  "1299628800000", "1336867200000", true, true);
TermRangeQuery nq1 = new TermRangeQuery("publish_date",  "1299628800", "1336867200", true, true); 
TermRangeQuery nq1 = new TermRangeQuery("publish_date",  "2012-09-10T00:00:00Z", "2012-10-10T00:00:00Z", true, true); 
TermRangeQuery nq1 = new TermRangeQuery("publish_date",  "20120910", "20121010", true, true);
```

Above ones won't work because you are using string parameter for numeric data.

```
NumericRangeQuery nq1 = NumericRangeQuery.newLongRange("publish_date", 1299628800, 1336867200, true, true);
```

This one wouldn't work because you didn't pad it with enough zeroes. 1299628800 stands for Fri Jan 16 02:00:28 GMT 1970.

If you have document(s) dated between 09/03/2011 and 13/05/2012, the following should work:

```
NumericRangeQuery nq1 = NumericRangeQuery.newLongRange("publish_date", 1299628800000L, 1336867200000L, true, true);
```

Comment: thank you mindas!! this seems to work, kind of... it only finds docs that have the exact value i supply. meaning it doesn't work as a range and it also doesn't work with null min or null max. I guess i'm doing something wrong but i'm not sure what. also isn't a range query very bad for performance when it comes to large ranges (like date)?  
I'd love to know how solr handles that field and what dose it do in background when receiving a query like this:  
publish_date:[2012-09-10T00:00:00Z TO *]

Comment: It started working when i push the precisionStep on my NumericRangeQuery way up (over 40). now i get results that are similar to the ones i get when using the solr admin interface.  
in solr's schema.xml date field is defined: 
    <fieldType name="date" class="solr.TrieDateField" omitNorms="true" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>  
I still don't understand what's lucene equivilent to **precisionStep 0** in other words what is the "right" NumericRangeQuery for a field defined as above

Comment: I think Solr's precisionStep just replicates Lucene's. You can read more on precision steps here: http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/what-is-precisionStep-and-positionIncrementGap-td3991706.html