# Lucene: How to construct a date range query programmatically?

Tags: lucene

Using Lucene 4.2.1 API, I need an equivalent of

> +fieldname:[2013-01-17T00:00:00Z TO *]

constructed programmatically.

I peeked at [TermRangeQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_2_1/core/org/apache/lucene/search/TermRangeQuery.html) and [NumericRangeQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_2_1/core/org/apache/lucene/search/NumericRangeQuery.html) but have not been able to come up with a quick solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lucene Query on a DateField indexed by Solr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953510/lucene-query-on-a-datefield-indexed-by-solr)

Comment: I don't see a straightforward answer there, although it gets me closer. Isn't here a one liner that could be extracted and save time for me and others that want to do this?

Comment: I think you need to re-read the answer for this question. There's clearly a solution there.

Comment: What I inferred from that answer is I should do a NumericRange query using timestamps (longs). This wouldn't work for me as I need to submit the query to **Solr** eventually and Solr accepts the date only in YYYY-MM-DDTxx:xx:xxZ format. So back to creating the query by hand.

Comment: Sorry, but your question/comment makes no sense. You asked how to make a query for **Lucene** and now out of a sudden you speak about **Solr**. You need to provide more details for people to help you.

Comment: You are correct in thath I didn't provide the context beginning. This was to simplify the question and concentrate on the specific issue. So, to clarify, what I do is, I construct a Lucene query, toString() it in the end and submit it to Solr. This has worked so far. But it likely won't work for dates. What I would have liked to have in the beginning was a way to construct a **Solr** query programmatically, but I haven't found an API to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query is no different from a range query, the only difference is that it expects to get the date formatted in [Solr format](http://docs.lucidworks.com/display/lweug/Solr+Date+Format).

You can use Solr's [`TrieDateField.getRangeQuery`](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_2_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/schema/TrieDateField.html) to construct this query. Tip: `QParser` parameter is ignored so you can just skip it.